# return id field when executing SQL in LINQ

Tags: linq

I'm trying to execute an SQL insert query using LINQ and returning the ID field.  My code does not work, can anybody tell me if my syntax is wrong?

```
string query = "insert into EnvironmentalReportDepts ";
                query += "(fkDeptID, OrderNumber, fkEnvironmentalReportID) ";
                query += "values(" + tmpDeptReport.fkDeptID + ", " + tmpDeptReport.OrderNumber + ", " + tmpDeptReport.EnvironmentalReport.EnvironmentalReportID + ") ";
                query += "select scope_identity()";

                var newDeptID = _database.ExecuteQuery<int>(query).ToList()[0];
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the entity to persist that record?

Comment: I need to use this method as I am working with a previously created page that has a load of inserts in a loop and the submitchanges line takes forever to run.

Comment: I understand. Generally, I'd use regular ADO.NET or the Data Access block which is part of the MS Enterprise Library for something like this.

Comment: Side note: Rather than `.ToList()[0]`, surely `.First()` would be simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
query += "select scope_identity()";
```

to

```
query += "; select scope_identity()";
```

Also, you may have to use

```
 _database.ExecuteQuery<decimal>(query).ToList()[0];
```

Comment: Re `decimal`: If the ID is an integral type (say, `INT`), you can also use `query += "; select CONVERT(INT, SCOPE_IDENTITY())"` and keep using `ExecuteQuery<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

change query to:

```
string query = "DECLARE @scope_identity int"; 
query += "insert into EnvironmentalReportDepts ";               
query += "(fkDeptID, OrderNumber, fkEnvironmentalReportID) ";                 
query += "values(" + tmpDeptReport.fkDeptID + ", " + tmpDeptReport.OrderNumber + ", " + tmpDeptReport.EnvironmentalReport.EnvironmentalReportID + ") ";
query += "SET @scope_identity=@@IDENTITY";                 
query += "select @scope_identity";
```